# LiveData confusion in [Android] Plaid App

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, plaid

I am referring to the Plaid open source project on github [Link to Plaid](https://github.com/android/plaid)

It is an excellent source to learn new techniques on Android.

As I was going through the code, I came across a certain style of coding around `LiveData` which I really didn't understand. If anybody can help me get it.
Here goes:

There's a `ViewModel(vm)` with this piece of code:

```
private val _openLink = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
val openLink: LiveData<Event<String>>
    get() = _openLink
```

Fairly simple? Note that, there are **2** variables here: `openLink` and `_openLink`. The getter for `openLink` is returning the `_openLink` LiveData.

In the activity they observe the `openLink` `LiveData` as follows:

```
viewModel.also { vm ->

       vm.openLink.observe(this, EventObserver { openLink(it) })

        ..... // Other stuff
}
```

Now, the other livedata `_openLink` is being called by the UI supposedly on a button click and it's defined like this:

```
fun viewShotRequested() {
    _shotUiModel.value?.let { model -> // ignore this part
        _openLink.value = Event(model.url) // setValue on _openLink
    }
}
```

So here my understanding is, on `setValue()` on `_openLink`,  `EventObserver{openLink(it)}` will get called. 
My question is, why have they done it like this?

**Questions:**

1. Why not observe *directly* on `_openLink`?
2. Will it not have the same effect? What am I missing here?

Comment: To not expose the *Mutable* part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_openLink` is mutable. You must always expose something which is immutable and cannot be changed by your observer, because that should only be done by your ViewModel, even though exposing `_openLink` would have no effect.

That's why you need to expose `openLink` which is immutable.

```
private val _openLink = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
val openLink: LiveData<Event<String>> = _openLink
```

Answer (score 1):

The `MutableLiveData` property shouldn't be exposed: it is mutable and could be changed anywhere across your program. 
That's why the `LiveData` is exposed instead: it is responsible for updating your property, and it uses the `MutableLiveData` as a backing field.

The exception to this would be two-way DataBinding, where direct access to the value would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why have they done it like this?

Because Google apparently enjoys writing more code for the sake of writing more code.

The supposed answer if you're inclined to believe them is that [`LiveData<Event<T>>` is preferred over `SingleLiveData` because they came up with it later than with `LiveData<Event<T>>` and is therefore supposedly better](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).

They intend to use an "enqueueable event-bus that forgets items after it is emitted to at least 1 observer", but Jetpack offers no such concept out of the box, personally [I had to write one of my own](https://github.com/Zhuinden/event-emitter).

Even so, there's a distinction between whether you can write into something, and whether you can only read from something but not write into it yourself. In this case, only the ViewModel wants to be able to emit events, so it is the ViewModel that holds a `Mutable__` reference, but exposes a regular `LiveData` to the outside world (in my case, `EventEmitter` vs `EventSource`).

As for the `_`, it's a Kotlin style convention that will hopefully be changed one day, as you could either do:

```
private val _openLink = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
val openLink: LiveData<Event<String>>
    get() = _openLink
```

But you could also do

```
private val openLink = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
fun openLink(): LiveData<Event<String>> = openLink
```

And that way we could ditch the `_` prefix in our own code, but for some reason the authors of Kotlin hadn't come up with that convention in time.

Comment: You're actually right. I had to use `Event<T>` and `SingleLiveEvent` just to get out of this mess and then I came across this code which added to my confusion.